# Sharing data between sibling components in angular using BehaviorService

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one object that gets loaded in a module load. I'd like to share it to a bunch of components within the module and have them dynamically update each other on changes. I'm trying to use BehaviorComponent and it's honestly...it's just way more complicated than it seems to need to be!

I cannot share the details of my project unfortunately, but basically my object looks like this.

```
ObjectType {
   ID: int;
   property1: string;
   property2: string;
   property3: AnotherObjectType[];
   property4: AnotherObjectType2[];   
};
```

It seems like you need to work some magic to get Behavior Subject to sync with complex objects vs just primitive types. Why on earth isn't there a better feature built into Angular (new to angular)? Am I missing something? Do I really need to do weird stuff like serializing the objects and pushing them onto arrays to get the changes to pickup?

Generally like Angular, but this seems so needlessly cumbersome, but hoping maybe there's a simpler way that I'm just overlooking.

Comment: Example of shared service https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401075/how-to-pass-data-to-two-level-three-level-down-in-angular-component-whats-the/76401141#76401141

Answer (score 0):

```
// Service
import { injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  message = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  
  getMessage(): any {
    return this.message.asObservable();
  } 

  sendMessage(data:any): any {
    this.message.next(data);
  }
}

// get data
constructor(private service: AuthService){
   this.service.getMessage().subscribe(response =>{
      this.data = response;
   });
}

//send data
this.service.sendMessage(data);
```

calling getMessage() from your service will helps you to get data from any component.

Comment: Almost works for me, but when I try to read the value I just get error : cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') with a bit of a call stack.

It's been set before attempting to read, and I was able to trace that, but genuinely this is such a simple concept it's almost making it hard to debug when it doesn't work.

Comment: I forgot to add return in getMessage function. I just made a correction. This code works fine now.