Passing data from one Component to another in Angular
I need to pass Data from one component  to another in Angular .
I have 2 components FinancedashboardComponent and Popupcomponent
on button click I  passed data from  FinancedashboardComponent  to  Popupcomponent
onButtonClick(rowData: any): void {
    alert(`CRID: ${rowData.crid}`);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
        width: '250px',
        data: {
            message: `CRID: ${rowData.crid}`,
            hi: "sdfsdmfs"
        }
        // Pass any data to the popup if needed
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log('The dialog was closed');
        // Handle any actions after the popup is closed
    });
}

here is my popup.ts file
@Component({
    selector: 'app-popup',
    templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./popup.component.css']
})
export class PopupComponent implements  OnInit{
    hh: any;

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PopupComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
        this.hh = data;
        console.log(this.hh);

        // here i am getting this value like this
        // { message: 'CRID: 2', hi: 'sdfsdmfs' }
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }

    closePopup(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}

I am able to pass data from finanacecomponent  to  poup.
this is the console.log output inside constructor of popup.ts file  .
/*
{message: 'CRID: 2', hi: 'sdfsdmfs'}
hi
:
"sdfsdmfs"
message
:
"CRID: 2"
[[Prototype]]
:
Object  */
but inside the  html file I  am unable to display data.
here is my html  popupcomponenet.html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Popup Content</h2>
    <p>Message: {{hh.message}}</p>  <!-- this is not displaying -->
</div>

I need to display data inside popup component but it is not displaying

please reproduce the issue on stackblitz and share back on the question

Try shared service https://stackoverflow.com/a/76401141/16396735

Please format your code, it is unreadable. Check also here on how to ask a question on stackoverflow. Your question is not following these guide-lines.

'
Popup Content
{{ hh.message }}

'   when I change html file like this and  input value in textbox , value is displaying inside  tag  . It is displaying value after an action.
Can someone help on this ?

It is now working.  Inside constructor  i called setTimeout(() => {
// Manually trigger change detection
this.cdr.detectChanges();
});  I called ChangeDetectorRef
